# throughout repairing, Apple provide a macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, repair, apple-store

I am thinking to give my macbook pro to apple service. Because on the right side, USB, hdmi and sd card reader are not working. According to the people in the store, it will take about 3-5 days to fix the problem.

But: I need a computer because I have to study and work on computer. 3-5 days are very important for me. Does any one know if i give my macbook to apple service, they provide me a laptop during repairing time ? If yes, I should pay or not? I still have guarantee..

Location : Bern/Switzerland

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple doesn't offer warranty replacement Macs during service unless you are paying / participating in the [Joint Venture program](https://jointventure.apple.com/). It's basically premium service that you pay for as an add-on similar to how AppleCare is an add on that can reduce your repair costs in some cases. I don't know how many countries it is offered, so contact your store's Business team to check. From the USA web site, the program has this as one of it's benefits:

> Premium access to Apple Support.
>
> You’ll get your own website with easy access to every service we offer
>   — custom training, Genius Bar reservations, tech support, and
>   workshops. And you can speak by phone to an Apple Genius who can help
>   resolve your issue, check into necessary parts, and estimate repair
>   turnaround time. We’ll even loan you a computer while yours is being
>   repaired. If you prefer to meet in person, you can make a Genius Bar
>   appointment at any Apple Store in the world.

You'll need to rent a replacement elsewhere before you turn in your computer or time the repair to when you can afford to lose the days it takes to do the work on it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. When I go there, I will ask about it.